# WebExtension browserAction.onClicked does not trigger

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my content script to work, all it contains is this :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.browserAction.disable(tab.id);
  console.log(tab.url);
});
```

I have added these lines in the manifest :

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab", "tabs"
  ],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/premod-32.png",
    "default_title": "Premod"
  },
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*"],
    "js": ["content_scripts/jquery.js", "content_scripts/premod.js"]
  }
]
```

I can see the browser action, but when I click on it, it does not get disabled and I can not see a log in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Solved : Code had to be in the background file.